# Activity Transition - how to?

Tags: android, android-transitions

I'm trying to achieve a transition animation something like below (Like when we click on a button in ActivityA, ActivityB slides up with some fade and when we click a button ActivityB, Activity A slides down from the top with a fade. )
But I'm not able to achieve it. Can someone help me with this?

[image]

Below is my code:

slide_in_top.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0" />
```

slide_out_bottom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="-100%p" />
```

MainActivity.kt

```
            startActivity(intent)
            overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_in_top, R.anim.slide_out_bottom );
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use Shared Transitions. Whether you go from Activity to Activity, or Fragment to Fragment, or recyclerview item to Activity.

Follow this [link](http://mikescamell.com/shared-element-transitions-part-1/). It helped me understand Shared Transitions better. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the link Subhasmith. But isn't the shared Transitions used for carrying(animate) an element from Activity A to Activity B like the one in my question above? I'm not looking for that type of transition. Instead I just need the animation like when we click on a button in ActivityA, ActivityB slides up with some fade and when we click a button ActivityB, Activity A slides down from the top with a fade

Comment: Gotcha. use overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.slide_down); and within that  you gotta create an anim drawable. Let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: Its all done. I added the code to my question. But I think I'm missing something in my code because of which the animation is not working correctly

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="75%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:duration="500"/>
</set> slideup.xmll

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <scale
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />

</set> slidedown.xml

Comment: Thanks for the code but the transition was not as smooth and same as what I wanted.